# What are appropriate measures to keep use of reference managers within the GDPR?

Tags: united-kingdom, data, legal-issues, eu

[The GDPR](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/) (or national legislation implementing it) places requirements on anyone who processes personally identifiable data concerning residents of the EU and the UK. As per [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79071/does-the-gdpr-apply-to-reference-managers) the GDPR applies to reference managers. While it seems that either legitimate interest or scientific or historical research purposes would provide justification for the processing, other sections of the law may impose requirements on individuals using these tools:

- Right to be informed

  - [Data subject have a right to be informed about data processing](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-to-be-informed/). One could easily inform each corresponding author that one is processing their data (this could be automated by the reference manager).  This could be viewed more as spam than useful information.
- International transfers

  - [There a a lot of rules](https://gdpr-info.eu/chapter-5/) governing transfer of PII to third parties, [with particular emphasis on the US](https://iapp.org/news/a/the-schrems-ii-decision-eu-us-data-transfers-in-question/).  Transferring ones reference manager database would seem to count as this, as would storing it online where it could be accessed by US law enforcement.
- You must not keep personal data for longer than you need it.

  - [The GDPR says](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/principles/storage-limitation/) "you must not keep personal data for longer than you need it".  How is this interpreted when it comes to reference managers?
- Security of data

  - [There is a requirement to keep data secure](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/security/).  Obviously reference manager software only holds public information, but there is no exception in the GDPR for this.  Should reference manager databases be considered high security documents such that extra security measures are taken?

What measures are appropriate to allow legal use of reference managers that contain data about authors who reside within the EU/UK?

Comment: I am certainly not a lawyer, but would have found it weird if this case was forgotten when drafting GDPR. The same problems are present when processing data about anybody "public", and I can't, for instance, imagine a newspaper sending a member of parliament a GDPR information note when starting to write an article about them. 

A quick google finds the following article: https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=cd8cdc5f-6f96-4032-9730-54a61d0eb045 - Here, there is a "journalistic exemption" mentioned, which also seems to include academic purposes. Perhaps that may apply here as well?

Comment: Personally, I think the answer to the question you linked (that GDPR applies to reference managers) is incorrect. Using similar logic one could imply that keeping a copy of Nature around after you've read it would violate the GDPR since, well, all that 'personal' data is just sitting there on your desk unprotected and unused. However, this question would be better off over on Law SE if you want a real answer.

Comment: @JonCuster My opinion is that the law was not intended to apply in these situations, but the way it was written it does.  I thought the linked question covered the legal aspects, and this the practical academic aspects.  A paper journal does not have "processing of personal data wholly or partly by automated means" so the GDPR does not apply.  A collection of journals organised by date may.

Comment: @User65535 - I'm pretty sure the full GDPR text is much longer than the snippet listed in the linked answer. Again, asking on Law SE would prove more fruitful than opinions here.

Comment: The way I understand this (again, IANAL), the article I linked to in a comment above explains that the GDPR itself applies to the author information, but the "journalistic exemption" frees the holder of the reference database from the relevant obligations that come with it in the way specified in the national laws. If that is really the case, the answer that the OP got on law.stackexchange is correct, but not helpful, because it doesn't clear this up.

Comment: @DCTLib - indeed, I don't think that answer there really delved into it. A little sleuthing came up with https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78685/does-the-gdpr-cover-reference-to-court-proceedings where "This condition is met if the processing relates to personal data which is manifestly made public by the data subject." is apparently in the GDPR as an exemption. If you don't want your name on a paper, use a pseudonym, other wise the 'data subject' made it public on purpose.

Comment: Given the advice to ask on law.SE, should I edit this information into the linked question, ask a new one or move this one (if I can)?